# how to find a file in a directory based on a known id in php?

Tags: php, regex, join, readdir

i have some images in a folder on a server:

```
/9_123456.jpg
/10_123457.jpg
/21_123458.jpg
/14_123459.jpg
...
```

also i have a database that holds those file names.

```
id    file
9     9_123456.jpg
10    10_123457.jpg
21    21_123458.jpg
14    14_123459.jpg
```

what i am doing at this point is query the picture name and show it on a webpage.

the issue is that i have millions of pictures and sometimes it takes a while for those images to come back, in special if i have to join that table with some other ones.

What i am thinking to do is to ignore that database table and write a php function that gets me the pic like this:

```
look in that directory and find a pic that begins with 9, or 10 , or whatever, because i know that number. some kind of a regexp.
```

my question is, will this method be faster than the query? and how would i look for that file?

hope i made myself clear enough.

thnaks

Comment: There's also a `glob()` function.

Comment: Somehow I think using proper indexes on the right columns will provide you with a fast lookup. That's what databases are made for right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to help you out: Try `glob($id.'_*.jpg');`

Performance depends on your system. Very generally speaking: On Windows it will be slower (due to the way the `*` semantics are built), on Unices YMMV. I have experienced excellent results with Linux and ReiserFS and very usable results with Linux and ext*. If many images are accessed, chances are, you have the directory in cache. Mind though, that memory pressure is an ingredient to this!

Comment: will this method be faster than the query?

Comment: "will this method be faster than the query?"  The only way to really know is to measure it yourself.